# How to use UDP-acquired literal byte data

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, literals

I've been using the following code to get the UDP data stream from a sender in my network:

```
import socket
import datetime

## Configs
UDP_IP = "169.254.67.186"
UDP_PORT = 5606 #PC1 uses 5606

## Creating socket object
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  #AF_INET specifies that IPs are going to be used. #DGRAM specifies that it is going to be under UDP
address = (UDP_IP,      # IP Address
           UDP_PORT)    # Port of that IP
sock.bind(address)

## Progrma startup message
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().time()
print("Initiating data print at:",timestamp)
print("-------------------------------------------")

i = 1

## Initiates loop to 'listen'
while i < 10:
    # Function to recieve data
    data,senderaddr = sock.recvfrom(10240000) # Argument is the buffer size (maximum size of data being received at once). # Two outputs are given, the "data" output and the "address from senders" output.
    print("Streaming:",data)
    i = i + 1
```

It is still in testing period, so that is why I'm only receiving 10 packets of data and ending the while loop. Anyway, the start of the variable 'data' is, currently:

[Start of 'data' variable values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwnRT.png)

This is basically the format I'm getting from the stream. Looking around I have learned this is a literal byte variable of Python 3 (I'm using P3), and there are a few ways of decoding it to useful strings which didn't work, such as

Method 1:

```
str(data, 'utf-8')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in
>   position 0: invalid continuation byte

Method 2:

```
import binascii
data.decode("utf-8")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in
>   position 0: invalid continuation byte

None of these really helped me. I noticed this format of *b"\xx0\x00\xx0\x00\x00\x00 ...* is not the common example used for literal bytes conversion. In the threads I found people are using more the format *b"abcdef"* to describe their problem (without backslashes, that seem to separate individual characters), so I guess I might be missing something here. It makes sense to think the methods I'm trying to use are not the right ones because of this part of the error messages:

> codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

So, could you guys help me telling me what I'm missing here?

Thank you

Comment: What is the data being send from the other end ?

Comment: @Dinesh Its an UDP feed from the game Project Cars. Check the two files in this repository: https://github.com/AlexandrePiccini/Personal . The packetsender_export is one packet of data received with the PacketSender program, although I could only get the Hex values through this method, and not the ones I'm having problem with. The udpDataSample is a data sample that doesn't represent the same data as before (respective to a different condition), received with Python, and it's just really a snippet of the entire string of data received (due to debugging reasons I broke it down to a small unit).

Comment: @AlexandrePiccini, did you ever find a resolution to this question? I am having a similar issue and have been stuck for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `data` bytearray does not represent `UTF-8` encoded data.

It makes sense that `\xd3` followed by a `\x04` is not a valid `UTF-8` sequence because according to the [UTf-8 specification (Wikipedia link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), values between `0x80` and `0x7FF` are to be represented by two bytes of the format `110x xxxx` and `10xx xxxx`, but more specifically because we are talking about the **Unicode Standard**, it means that anywhere from `\xc2` to `\xdf` for the first byte and `\x80` to `\xbf` for the second byte, hence a `\xd3` that is not preceeded by anything between `\x80` and `\xbf` is not a valid unicode formation.

Demonstration:

`b'\xd3\x80'.decode('utf-8')` => `I` (which is the ***CYRILLIC LETTER PALOCHKA*** U+04C0)

if we go one lower:
`b'\xd3\x79'.decode('utf-8')` it will throw an `UnicodeDecodeError` as to why `\x79` is `0111 1001` in binary, and not matching the `1xxx xxxx` pattern established for `UTF-8`.